# zpool import of destroyed pool

Tags: zfs

I'm trying to import a zpool that's on an attached USB disk, and `zpool import` isn't finding it.  Is there more debugging/troubleshooting I can do?

```
root@bierstadt:~# zdb -l /dev/sdb1
------------------------------------
LABEL 0
------------------------------------
    version: 5000
    name: 'neo'
    state: 2
    txg: 2165602
    pool_guid: 9181581013277384632
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'helo'
    top_guid: 13889219726875111043
    guid: 13889219726875111043
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 0
        guid: 13889219726875111043
        path: '/dev/sdd1'
        whole_disk: 1
        metaslab_array: 34
        metaslab_shift: 34
        ashift: 12
        asize: 3000474533888
        is_log: 0
        DTL: 209
        create_txg: 4
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
    labels = 0 1 2 3
root@bierstadt:~# zpool import
no pools available to import
root@bierstadt:~# zpool list
no pools available
```

**Update**: Updated the title to make it clear that this was a destroyed pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the great help in #zfsonlinux on freenode, I was able to find the answer.

```
state: 2
```

means 'Destroyed pool', and the key to getting around that is:

```
zpool import -D
```

Then:

```
zpool import -D <pool name, or id>
```

Which will un-destroy it and import it.  As for how it was destroyed, this is an old disk and that I'm going through and cleaning out, so it's not surprising that it's in that state, but I wouldn't have even thought to look at that `state: 2` bit.